# Stored TextField into custom class

Tags: ios, swift, class, store

I'm currently doing a login system test, I'd like to log in the accountTextfield of the string stored in the Account I built the class, so I can use in other controllers, this method should be how to achieve, can anyone help me, thank you

Here is class of Account

```
class Account {
var id:String?

init(id:String)
self.id = id 
}
```

And here is my `LoginViewController`

```
@IBOutlet weak var accountTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var passwordTextField: UITextField!

@IBAction func DoLogin(_ sender: AnyObject) {
  login_now(username:accountTextField.text!,password:passwordTextField.text!)

}

 func login_now(username:String, password:String)
 {
     let parameters = ["account": accountTextField.text!, "password": passwordTextField.text!] as Dictionary<String, String>

     let url = URL(string: "http://163.18.22.78/api/Login")!  
.
.
.
}
```

Comment: What is your issue?

Comment: I want save accountTextField.text in to the class Account(id)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Account: NSObject {
    var id:String?
} 

class Apimanager: NSObject {
    static let instance = Apimanager() 
    var user :Account = Account() 
} 

func login_now(username:String, password:String)
     {
         let parameters = ["account": accountTextField.text!, "password": passwordTextField.text!] as Dictionary<String, String>      
         Apimanager.instance.user.id = accountTextField.text!
         print(Apimanager.instance.user.id!)
     }
```

In another view controller

```
Print(Apimanager.instance.user.id!
```

if you want use init() method in Account class then you can use

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(accountTextField.text!, forKey: "account")
UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
```

to store particular value and to get value in another view controller you can use

```
print(UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "account"))..
```

note that both key value should be match for setting and getting value from UserDefaults..hope it work for you!!

Comment: So simple, I will try later

Comment: But the objAccount is an object that create in the LoginViewController,can we use this string in anthor controller

Comment: Do I built anthor Apimanager class?And what do I fill in the var user:Account = Account(id:???)

Comment: sorry i was forgot to remove class init method...check updated answer

Comment: if you have one value then you can use UserDefaults.standard.set("accountTextField.text!", forKey: "account") for storing value and if you have more value so it's better to make class..

Comment: Thank you, I'll try your method and give you response